# Components not rendered correctly in React, they do render on browserrefresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have set up the `App.js` that links my components to their pages. Everything worked fine. Pages changed when clicked. I needed to change the header too for different pages, so I made a new Route-file like `App.js` but then for my header, called `Headers.js`. This file contains all the possible headers I can have on all my pages. I also linked this file in my `index.js`. The thing is now, all my headers change on click, like they are supposed to, but now my actual content, the application itself, doesn't. It changes when the refreshaction is used, which is not how is is supposed to go. I want everything to change when I press a link, not only the header. In my `index.html` file, `<div class="header">` and `<div class="root">` are specified.

The header does change like supposed to
The content for `App.js` does not, it changes when I refresh the page.

---

```
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Headers from './components/Header/Headers';
import App from './components/App/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Headers />, document.getElementById('header'));
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: bitlyshortenedURL i had to delete in stackoverflow cus of errors
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

---

```
App.js

//dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

//components
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
import Home from '../Pages/Home';
import StudentOverview from '../Pages/StudentOverview';
import StudentsPerClass from '../Pages/StudentsPerClass';
import StudentsPerSubject from '../Pages/StudentsPerSubject';
import StudentDetails from '../Pages/StudentDetails';
import Management from '../Pages/Management';
import StudentAdd from '../Pages/StudentAdd';
import Exercise from '../Exercise/Exercise';
import NameWithFaceMC from '../Exercise/NameWithFaceMC';
import NameWithFace from '../Exercise/NameWithFace';
import FaceWithName from '../Exercise/FaceWithName';

//includes
import '../../public/css/kdg-fonts.css';
import '../../public/css/normalize.css';
import '../../public/css/responsive.css';
import '../../public/css/say-my-name.css';
import '../../public/css/style.css';
import '../../public/css/style.min.css';
import '../../public/js/main.js';

//Run
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route exact path='/studenten' component={StudentOverview} />
          <Route exact path='/studentenperklasgroep' component={StudentsPerClass} />
          <Route exact path='/studentenpervak' component={StudentsPerSubject} />
          <Route exact path='/studenten/detail/:id' component={StudentDetails} />
          <Route exact path='/beheer' component={Management} />
          <Route exact path='/beheer/add' component={StudentAdd} />
          <Route exact path='/oefenen' component={Exercise} />
          <Route exact path='/oefenen/nbgmc' component={NameWithFaceMC} />
          <Route exact path='/oefenen/nbg' component={NameWithFace} />
          <Route exact path='/oefenen/gbn' component={FaceWithName} />
          <Route path='*' component={Footer} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

```
package.json

{
  "name": "saymyname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-changed": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Added video of what I am getting in the browser:
https://i.gyazo.com/99daa742967947c1e779917bd18a1182.mp4
Like I said, the page shows the content it should display on refresh in the browser.

If any more code or screenshots or video's are needed, please tell me and I'll provide. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the approach: what you just did in index.js is instantiating two different React applications, which is kind of wrong.

You should have just one entry point for the application (App.js in the #root div) and put the logic for the Header change inside it.

There are many ways to acheive what you are trying to do but it basically depends on how much your Headers differ from each other.

If, for example what changes is the text or the links, you colud create a generic Header component, import it into your pages and pass to it the text, or an array of links or whatever other things you may need as props.

Comment: I have tried that before but I did not work so I tried this approach